# IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter

Tags: hibernate

i am getting following Exception while `saving object`

```
IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [com.rasvek.cg.entity.AssocClassSubject.assocClassSubjectPKId (expected type = java.lang.Integer)]; target = [com.rasvek.cg.entity.AssocClassSubject@1e254e0], property value = [POST_INSERT_INDICATOR]
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl.set(SetterMethodImpl.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Component$ValueGenerationPlan.execute(Component.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.id.CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.generate(CompositeNestedGeneratedValueGenerator.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:660)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:652)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:647)
    at com.rasvek.cms.dao.MasterDaoImpl.updateClassSubjectMapping(MasterDaoImpl.java:2074)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy544.updateClassSubjectMapping(Unknown Source)
    at com.rasvek.cms.service.MasterSeviceImpl.updateClassSubjectMapping(MasterSeviceImpl.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy545.updateClassSubjectMapping(Unknown Source)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.MasterController.updateClassSubjectMapping(MasterController.java:1617)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.MasterController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2eff8c2.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.invoke(AfterReturningAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.rasvek.cms.controller.MasterController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$43169cd4.updateClassSubjectMapping(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1100)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:687)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.SetterMethodImpl.set(SetterMethodImpl.java:44)
    ... 97 more
```

Actually this `assocClassSubjectPKId`  is integer in my entity class even though 
its  asking like **(expected type = java.lang.Integer)**

please look at my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "assoc_class_subject", catalog = "campus_guru_01")
public class AssocClassSubject implements java.io.Serializable {

    private AssocClassSubjectId id;
    private MasterCampusClass masterCampusClass;
    private MasterSubject masterSubject;
    private Integer assocClassSubjectPKId;




    public AssocClassSubject() {
    }


    public AssocClassSubject(AssocClassSubjectId id, MasterCampusClass masterCampusClass, MasterSubject masterSubject) {
        this.id = id;
        this.masterCampusClass = masterCampusClass;
        this.masterSubject = masterSubject;
    }

    @EmbeddedId

    @AttributeOverrides({ @AttributeOverride(name = "classId", column = @Column(name = "class_id", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "subjectId", column = @Column(name = "subject_id", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "subjectOrder", column = @Column(name = "subject_order")),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "subjectExclude", column = @Column(name = "subject_exclude", length = 45)) })




    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)  

    @Column(name = "class_subject_mapping_id", unique = true, nullable = false)

    public Integer getAssocClassSubjectPKId() {
    return assocClassSubjectPKId;
}
    public void setAssocClassSubjectPKId(Integer assocClassSubjectPKId) {
        this.assocClassSubjectPKId = assocClassSubjectPKId;
    }


    public AssocClassSubjectId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(AssocClassSubjectId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "class_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public MasterCampusClass getMasterCampusClass() {
        return this.masterCampusClass;
    }

    public void setMasterCampusClass(MasterCampusClass masterCampusClass) {
        this.masterCampusClass = masterCampusClass;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public MasterSubject getMasterSubject() {  
        return this.masterSubject;
    }

    public void setMasterSubject(MasterSubject masterSubject) {
        this.masterSubject = masterSubject;
    }

}
```

why its gives this exception even its an Integer ?

what wrong i did ? not able to trace it. please help me.

thank you!.

**edit**

can any one tell what exactly this line means

```
IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter for property [com.rasvek.cg.entity.AssocClassSubject.assocClassSubjectPKId(expected type = java.lang.Integer)]; target = [com.rasvek.cg.entity.AssocClassSubject@1aeba13], property value = [POST_INSERT_INDICATOR]
```

Comment: when you get this error on  compilation or when you are calling setter method?

Comment: Also, check for import.

Comment: Exception trace it self telling while calling setter method.

Comment: then check datatype which you are sending to setter method...

Comment: i don't think your code has problem.

Comment: data type is integer only.

Comment: You placed the annotation for the id on top of the wrong setter and getter.
Also autogeneration of an embeddedId is impossible.

Comment: thank you @Zeromus can you please explain i did not get it

Comment: i suppose your Id is the field id.
But your annotation are on assocClassSubjectPKId getter and setter.

Comment: sorry i m not getting

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solved it by changing the Entity class follows

```
package com.rasvek.cg.entity;
// Generated Jun 1, 2018 11:33:12 PM by Hibernate Tools 5.1.7.Final

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * AssocClassSubject generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "assoc_class_subject", catalog = "campus_guru_01")
public class AssocClassSubject implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer classSubjectMappingId;
    private MasterCampusClass masterCampusClass;
    private MasterSubject masterSubject;
    private Integer subjectOrder;
    private String subjectExclude;

    public AssocClassSubject() {
    }

    public AssocClassSubject(MasterCampusClass masterCampusClass, MasterSubject masterSubject) {
        this.masterCampusClass = masterCampusClass;
        this.masterSubject = masterSubject;
    }

    public AssocClassSubject(MasterCampusClass masterCampusClass, MasterSubject masterSubject, Integer subjectOrder,
            String subjectExclude) {
        this.masterCampusClass = masterCampusClass;
        this.masterSubject = masterSubject;
        this.subjectOrder = subjectOrder;
        this.subjectExclude = subjectExclude;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "class_subject_mapping_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getClassSubjectMappingId() {
        return this.classSubjectMappingId;
    }

    public void setClassSubjectMappingId(Integer classSubjectMappingId) {
        this.classSubjectMappingId = classSubjectMappingId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "class_id", nullable = false)
    public MasterCampusClass getMasterCampusClass() {
        return this.masterCampusClass;
    }

    public void setMasterCampusClass(MasterCampusClass masterCampusClass) {
        this.masterCampusClass = masterCampusClass;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "subject_id", nullable = false)
    public MasterSubject getMasterSubject() {
        return this.masterSubject;
    }

    public void setMasterSubject(MasterSubject masterSubject) {
        this.masterSubject = masterSubject;
    }

    @Column(name = "subject_order")
    public Integer getSubjectOrder() {
        return this.subjectOrder;
    }

    public void setSubjectOrder(Integer subjectOrder) {
        this.subjectOrder = subjectOrder;
    }

    @Column(name = "subject_exclude", length = 45)
    public String getSubjectExclude() {
        return this.subjectExclude;
    }

    public void setSubjectExclude(String subjectExclude) {
        this.subjectExclude = subjectExclude;
    }

}
```

thank you every one !.

Comment: That's a huge thing to read. Would be nice if you can you point out what exactly you changed in the class that made it work?